# WebStorm wrapper text with square brackets

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I select some text, for example `form-col` and press `[` I want to get `[form-col]` but WebStorm replace selected text with `[`. Is there a way to configure it?

Comment: I don't think this functionality is there.

Comment: In phpStorm it works fine so I keep some hope

Comment: Does it work in WebStorm with `"` character? If it does then it should with `[` as well.

Comment: The same thing with quotes `"`. In phpStorm everything is fine

Comment: Well -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys  --> Surround selection on typing quote or brace` -- do you have such option enabled? **P.S.** Consider using `@username` otherwise there will be no notifications...

Comment: @LazyOne Perfect :) That's it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that functionality exist. However you can use the `Live template` functionality. It's very useful and it does pretty much the same thing.

To do this, go on : [File]->[Settings]->[Editor]->[Live Templates]->user, Click button + and add a live template like:

[image: add live template]

In you html file when you write the abbreviation what you are added, press Tab and it generate you `[]` and place the cursor after the first `[`and now  you can write your html tag `[form-col]`

Answer (score 0):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Smart Keys`
3. Ensure that `Surround selection on typing quote or brace` option is enabled